# Intuition to the solution to "the probability that during a photo shoot with $n$ people, two specific individuals stand at the ends"

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The original question's this: If $(n-2)$ students and $2$ teachers stand in a row for a photograph, randomly, find the probability that the $2$ teachers stand at the two ends.

Applying some simple counting methods yield the solution: $2!(n-2)!/n!$ ($2!$ permutations for teachers, times $(n-2)!$ permutations for students, divided by $n!$ total permutations possible).

Note that this is exactly the same as $1/(nC2)$, where $nC2$ denotes the number of ways of choosing $2$ objects from $n$ (the binomial coefficient).

MY question is: why is this true? Why should the probability of a specific permutation be the same as the reciprocal of the combinations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can see $n \choose 2$ as the number of ways to choose $2$ people out of all $n$ to stand at the end. For the teachers to stand at the end necessarily, there's only $1$ way to do so (that is, to choose the two teachers). The number of ways is thus $\frac{1}{n \choose 2}$.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thats really understandable.

Answer (score 3):

Because out of the $\binom n2$ possible ways to choose which two people are at the ends of the line, you only want to count the one where it is the two teachers.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!